# How to get a subset of rows from every group

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

Given a pandas DataFrame's groupby object `by_name`, I want to be able to select n rows from each group.

I was hoping `.tail()` function can do it, but it failed.

```
d = {
    'name': ['Tom', 'John', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'John'],
    'age': [18,54,27,44,12]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

by_name = df.groupby('name') 
two_rows_each = by_name.tail(2)
```

Well, it does select the number of rows I want but I can't apply `size()` method on this new object.

```
print two_rows_each.size()
```

raises `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'size'`

Though I can use `size()` on the original groupby `by_name`:

```
name
John    2
Tom     3
dtype: int64
```

I need both, to select X rows from the grouped object and later on get the sizes of  groups.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to get?

Comment: A groupby object with only two occurrences in each group (given the above code) such that I can use the `size()` method on it.

Comment: There is no `size` as the error states, are you after `shape`?

Comment: Why there is no size? `by_name` object does have size, and is identical per se

Comment: No it is not, groupby is a an object that describes how to perform the grouping, it is not a dataframe.

Comment: Well, I can do `by_name.size()` and no exception is raised.

Comment: @nutship that doesn't detract from the fact that there is no `size` attribute or method for a dataframe, you must use `shape`, they are completely different object types

Comment: Did not know about this property, thanks. Perhaps you could put that in an answer, so that I can mark as solved?

Comment: @Update, shape doesn't solve my problem actually, since it returns a scalar, I need size of every group.

Comment: @nutship does `by_name.count()` give you what you want?

Comment: No,it does not. Please see the OP updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand you, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
    'name': ['Tom', 'John', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'John','Mike'],
    'age': [18,54,27,44,12,90]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1 = df.groupby('name').tail(2)
print df1.groupby('name').size()
```

Just added `Mike` to get at least a value different of 2 at the end ;)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I needed. Oddly enough, I got the `AssertionError()` later in my code, I have to check what causes this, and later will get back to accept this one.